# Making values in to objects using Regex (Java)

Tags: java, regex, parsing

I have some data that looks like this

```
myobject{keyone:"valueone",keytwo:"valuetwo",keythree:"valuethree"}
myobject{keyone:"valueone",keytwo:"valuetwo",keythree:"valuethree"}
myobject{keyone:"valueone",keytwo:"valuetwo",keythree:"valuethree"}
```

And I'm wondering what the best way to create a bunch of objects from it would be. I've written the following regex to extract all the values from a particular Key...

```
Pattern p_keyone            = Pattern.compile("keyone:\"(.+?)\"\\,"); 
Matcher match_keyone    = p_keyone.matcher(string);

while(match_keyone.find()) {      
    myobjects.add(new MyObject(match_keyone.group(1));
}
```

Which gives me a bunch of objects with a single argument...

`myobjects.add(<valueone>);`

Is there a way I can execute a single regex query and create a bunch of objects with all the values as arguments in one go. Like this...

```
new MyObject( <valueone>, <valuetwo> , <valuethree> );
```

Thanks

Comment: Look like JSON, no ? so why not using a JSON Serializer/Deserializer like GSON ?

Comment: @Alois: Right, I thought that, too, but didn't take it into account in my answer. Why not turn your comment into an answer? I would upvote it :-)

Comment: @Ally, is it necessary to use Regular Expression? can you do other parsing means without RegExp?

Comment: @Alois Cochard and @chiccodoro, it's not JSON, as `keyone` appears twice (JSON must have unique key). If it was JSON, `keyone` should have been an array.

Comment: I'm trying to scrap some data from JavaScript (in a webpage) so there's a lot of rubbish in between for object creation etc as well as surrounding HTML. I did think of removing all those statements and parsing it but I think Regex would be a simpler solution (proving there's a way)

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman, what other way?

Comment: Using String's `split()`, `startsWith()` and `endsWith()` methods. Use those functions to parse the data you received.

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman: I'm pretty sure it's a copy-paste error in Ally's question, is it? It should be `keyone:"valueone",keytwo:"valuetwo"`...

Comment: @everyone - sorry The Elite Gentleman is right. It should be keyone:"valueone",keytwo:"valuetwo"

Comment: @Ally, you meant to say that chiccodoro is right! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is not bad.

Few things you could change, though it depends on your requirements whether they make sense:

- Create a "Factory" class which takes 1 line of data and creates the object.
- Read the data line by line, for each line use the Factory to create it.
- Depending on how fancy (and error-prone) you want it to get, you could even read the names of the objects and properties and then use reflection to create instances and set the properties.

Answer (score 0):

`String.split()` could help:

```
 String line = "myobject{keyone:\"valueone\",keytwo:\"valuetwo\",keythree:\"valuethree\"}"
             // ^-----[0]------^  ^--[1]-^  ^--[2]-^  ^--[3]-^  ^--[4]---^  ^--[5]---^  ^[6]
 String[] parts = line.split("\"");
 MyObject myObject = new MyObject(parts[1], parts[3], parts[5]);
```